# Change the color of divider in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, nine-patch

May I know how I can change the color of divider in `LinearLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dip"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:background="#ff2d2d2d" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Do I need to manually copy 9 patch image from Android SDK into my project, and define my own attribute to refer it?

Comment: Yes, You can create your own image(dividerVertical) and put it in drawable and can use it using android:divider="@drawable/dividerVertical". I have tried at my end and its working

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like `android:divider` attribute doesn't accept a color value. So you have to create a separate divider drawable in order to get it works:

divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="1dip" />
    <solid android:color="#f00" />

</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerPadding="12dip"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:background="#ff2d2d2d" >
```

Also, please note that `android:divider` is only available in android 3.0 or higher and it doesn't work in previous android versions.

Comment: You should get rid of the invalid answer.

Comment: how come i can't see the divider when using this xml ? i've even tried to use a different width for it and show the dividers on all cases...

Comment: I think divider attrib no longer works. There is the View solution which does not depend on this attribute.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I did it

```
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVwmarkupborder"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:src="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

In my method i am use this one..

Comment: I know such method. I just wish to use the android:divider feature