# Custom divider not working in Linear layout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I want to change the color of my Divider for that I am following solution : [Change the color of divider in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170790/change-the-color-of-divider-in-linearlayout). but my divider not showning

Code :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="@drawable/devider"
        android:dividerPadding="12dip"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"

        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="This is demo of Boderless Button"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_datarecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Divide Drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="5dip" />
    <solid android:color="#f00" />
</selector>
```

observed thing : if I use `android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"` then divider is working

Comment: Dud you try <shape> instead of <selector> ?

Comment: @thanks for remind me that , that solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your drawable xml like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="5dip" />
    <solid android:color="#f00" />
</shape>
```